# R package depending on Boost

Tags: c++, r, boost, r-package, cran

I am particularly happy of two R packages I recently developed. But unfortunately, they are not acceptable by CRAN because of a warning spotted by R CMD CHECK, which comes from the **BH** package. For Windows I have a solution: the C++ library **Boost** is included in **Rtools 4.2** so my packages don't need the **BH** package. Some R packages require an external library, and I'm wondering if I could require a dependency to **Boost** on Linux and Mac. The **av** package requires the **ffmpeg** library, and I took a look at its [configure script](https://github.com/ropensci/av/blob/8f70dcaa67c039a9be52b19584894684a2d22b60/configure) but I'm not able to understand it. Would you know whether I can include such a script for **Boost**, and what this script should contain?

Comment: R already depends on Boost, so this shouldn't be a problem: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/index.html

Comment: As I said, I can't use **BH**, because of a warning.

Comment: Shouldn't you submit a bug report to BH?

Comment: More details about the warning would be useful and what your Makevars/Makevars.win look like. It's unusual that you cant use the BH package's headers.

Comment: @stephematician This issue has been fixed by CRAN now.

Comment: Anyway this question was not about solving the warning...